# Why $\forall{f\in \omega^{\omega}\cap V}$ $ \forall^{\infty}n f(n)\neq f_{G}(n)$

Tags: set-theory, forcing

**Eventually different forcing**, $\mathbb{E}=\{\langle s,H \rangle:s \in \omega^{\omega}\wedge H\subseteq [\omega^{\omega}]^{<\omega}\}$.

ordered by $(s',H')\leq (s,H)$ iff $s \subseteq s'$ and $H \subseteq H'$ and $\forall{i \in \text{dom}(s'\setminus s)}\forall{g \in H'}(s(i)\neq g(i))$. It generically adds a new real $f_{G}=\bigcup\{s:\exists{H}(s,H)\in G\}$.

If  $f_{G}=\bigcup\{s:\exists{H}(s,H)\in G\}$. Why $\forall{f\in \omega^{\omega}\cap V}$ $ \forall^{\infty}n f(n)\neq f_{G}(n)$.

Also. I do not understand why $\mathbb{E}$ adds a function $f_{G}\in \omega^{\omega}$.

Any contribution, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** For every $f\in\omega^\omega\cap V$, consider the set as defined in $V$, $D_f=\{(p,H)\in\mathbb E\mid f\in H\}$. Show it's dense, and use genericity to conclude that $f_G$ is new and has the wanted property.

Comment: I think you want a slightly different $D_f$. With yours, the generic filter could meet $D_f$ by containing just one $(p,H)$ with $p\not\subseteq f$.  That's enough to make $f_G$ different from $f$, but the OP wants it to be almost everywhere different.  I suggest taking $D_f$ to consist of conditions such that some $f'\in H$ is almost everywhere equal to $f$.

Comment: @Andreas: If $f\in H$, then for every extension of $(p,H)$, $(p',H')$ every $i\in\operatorname{dom}(p'\setminus p)$, $p'(i)\neq f(i)$.

Comment: I agree with what you wrote about "if $f\in H$". My problem is with the case where $f\notin H$ but $p\not\subseteq f$.  Such a pair $(p,H)$ would be in your $D_f$ but wouldn't produce enough (meaning cofinitely much) disagreement between $f_G$ and $f$.

Comment: Ah. With that I agree, and to be honest, I sort of hedged, because that was my first guess. I don't know why I hedged, though. Thanks!